Traefik HTTP Basic Auth for Dashboard not working
In the end, after a LOT of time spent on configuration, I’m out of ideas. Something that’s supposed to be quite simple is becoming rather complicated. Hopefully, someone else can help me find the solution.
I’m trying to run a container with Traefik. Instead of putting all the configuration in the container's docker-compose file (docker-compose.yml), as many people do, I’m placing the configuration in a dedicated file (traefik.yml) since that’s more flexible for me.
I have the following docker-compose.yml file for Traefik:
version: "3.8"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    hostname: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - "--configFile=/traefik.yml"
    networks:
      - traefik_gw_bridge
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - logs:/logs
      - letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 6s
      retries: 2
      start_period: 5s

networks:
  traefik_gw_bridge:
    driver: bridge
    external: true

volumes:
  letsencrypt:
  logs:

And these are the configuration parameters I am using for traefik.yml:
api:
  dashboard: true     
  insecure: false    

ping:
  entryPoint: web      

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false 

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"   
  websecure:
    address: ":443"   
  traefik:
    address: ":8080" 

http:
  routers:
    dashboard:
      rule: "Host(`traefikdash.mydomain.com`)" 
      entryPoints:
        - traefik
      service: api@internal
      middlewares:
        - auth

  middlewares:
    auth:
      basicAuth:
        users:
          - "admin:$apr1$Nzj4xQwY$QiXQ/eYHzKTFS.Lx.6XG71"

log:                              
  filePath: "/logs/traefik.log"
  format: json
  level: DEBUG

accessLog:                        
  filePath: "/logs/access.log"
  bufferingSize: 150

certificatesResolvers:
  le:    
    acme:
      email: "example@email.com"    
      storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json"  
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: "web" 

Logically, in the following part of the configuration file, I am trying to define a router to set up basic authentication with a username and password for the Dashboard:
http:
  routers:
    dashboard:
      rule: "Host(`traefikdash.mydomain.com`)"  # Reemplaza `yourdomain.com` con tu dominio
      entryPoints:
        - traefik
      service: api@internal
      middlewares:
        - auth

  middlewares:
    auth:
      basicAuth:
        users:
          - "admin:$apr1$Nzj4xQwY$QiXQ/eYHzKTFS.Lx.6XG71"

I am unable to get the result I want. When I access traefikdash.mydomain.com or traefikdash.mydomain.com:8080 or traefikdash.mydomain.com:8080/dashboard / traefikdash.mydomain.com/dashboard, I simply get the following responses from Traefik and my browser:

HTTP 404 Page not found
Error connection refused

After trying various types of configurations, I simply can't find much more information on how to implement HTTP basic auth to access the Traefik Dashboard.

Finally, I found the solution.
The Traefik documentation isn't bad, but sometimes it isn't very specific either, and I needed to rely on the StackOverflow community to find the answer definitively.
Traefik handles dedicated configurations (configuration files) in different ways.

Static configuration of Traefik = traefik.yml
Dynamic configuration of Traefik = config.yml

The dynamic configuration is basically the configuration of routers and middlewares provided to each provider, in my case, Static File Configuration.
So, finally, from traefik.yml, you need to reference a dynamic configuration file where you can implement HTTP Basic Auth, as follows:

traefik.yml:

    api:
      dashboard: true     
      insecure: false   
    
    ping:
      entryPoint: web    
    
    providers:
      docker:
        endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        exposedByDefault: false 
      file:                 
        filename: /config.yml   
        watch: true
    
    entryPoints:
      web:
        address: ":80"    
      websecure:
        address: ":443"  
      traefik:
        address: ":8080"  
    
    log:                              
      filePath: "/logs/traefik.log"
      format: json
      level: DEBUG
    
    accessLog:            
      filePath: "/logs/access.log"
      bufferingSize: 150
    
    certificatesResolvers:
      le:   
        acme:
          email: "email@youremail.com"    
          storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json"   
          httpChallenge:
            entryPoint: "web"


config.yml:

    http:
      routers:
        dashboard:
          rule: "Host(`yourdomain.domain.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - traefik
          service: api@internal
          middlewares:
            - auth
    
      middlewares:
        auth:
          basicAuth:
            users:
              - "user:password"

In this way, when I accessed my URL domain, e.g., yourdomain.domain.com:8080, it correctly prompted me for user authentication.
